# NullReference Error while reading xlsx EPPlus Core

Tags: asp.net-core, epplus

I'm trying to upload an excel file with EPPlus. I'ts like my excel file was empty, but it has content inside.

Im getting this error:
**worksheet.Dimension.Rows = 'worksheet.Dimension.Rows' threw an exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException'**

on this line: int rowCount = worksheet.Dimension.Rows;

```
[HttpPost("Excel")]
    public string UploadExcel(IFormFile file)
    {
        var filePath = Path.GetTempFileName();
        FileInfo excel = new FileInfo(filePath);

        using (ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage(excel))
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            ExcelWorksheet worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets[file.FileName];

            int rowCount = worksheet.Dimension.Rows;
            int ColCount = worksheet.Dimension.Columns;
            bool bHeaderRow = true;
            for (int row = 1; row <= rowCount; row++)
            {
                for (int col = 1; col <= ColCount; col++)
                {
                    if (bHeaderRow)
                    {
                        sb.Append(worksheet.Cells[row, col].Value.ToString() + "\t");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        sb.Append(worksheet.Cells[row, col].Value.ToString() + "\t");
                    }
                }
                sb.Append(Environment.NewLine);
            }
            return sb.ToString();
        }
```

Comment: In a nutshell, you're trying to access a member of an instance that evaluates to null at runtime. While the the type of that instance has the member, null does not. Debug your code and find the null. Then, figure out why it's null and add appropriate null guards or fix the error that's causing it to be null in the first place.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? For `UploadExcel`, it seems you accept an excel file and return this content, is this your requirement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you verify that the workshseets are being loaded?

```
//examine in the debugger to make sure the worksheet you want is loaded
var worksheets = package.Workbook.Worksheets.ToList();
```

If that doesn't work, can you try one of these?

```
var worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets[0];
var worksheetFirst = package.Workbook.Worksheets.First();
```

UPDATE:

The real error is that you are trying to read a temp file with `var filePath = Path.GetTempFileName();`. You need to read an actual excel file. For example, you could use `Path.GetFullPath("path/to/the/excel/file.xls");`

Comment: when I try these I get: "File info does not contain a definition for Workbook..."

Comment: sorry, not `excel.`, use `package.` - my mistake (I updated my answer).

Comment: When I try with .First(); it says "System.InvalidOperationException: 'Sequence contains no elements", it is like nothing is in my excel file. And [0] says position out of range.

Comment: that means your excel file is bad. looking more closely...why are you trying to load a temp file? see `var filePath = Path.GetTempFileName();`. Aren't you trying to load an excel file that already exists on your machine?

Comment: Yes. I want to get the data from an excel file that I will get through the front-end. How would you do that?

Comment: I would break-up these two actions. First, have the user upload their excel file and then save that file to your machine. Second, read that file into EPPlus. Maybe use `var filePath = Path.GetFullPath("path/to/the/excel/file");`